# Is it ok if I misspell the mantras as I am a beginner?

Tags: mantras

I want to learn and chant some mantras to control my stress,fear and to control my sensual feelings(I am also planning to do meditation to control my stress). From where should I start ? Is it okay if I misspell the mantras ?

Comment: You should learn mantras from Guru or a learned Acharya and thereby you don't misspell them.

Comment: You shouldn't misspell the mantras because they are powerful and may give negative effects if misspelled. Learn mantras from a guru or an experienced person. Many feel something is better than nothing but nothing is better than non sense.

Comment: Fear Not! As long as you have faith in Sri Rama, no unintentional misspell of mantra can ever harm you. God sees your dedication not your pronunciation.

Answer (score 1):

In the process of learning the beginner is bound to make mistakes.

Even if one learns from a guru in the gurukulam he is bound to make mistakes.

No one can do correct chanting from the word go. Hence there should not be any guilt about it.

But efforts should be made to minimize the mistakes by careful observation of chanting and pronunciation. One should try not to repeat same mistakes again.

If you are wishing to learn the Vedas and wondering where to learn from then you can see the list of paathashalas [here](http://msrvvp.ac.in/Annual_Report_english_2011_12.pdf) (from page no. 40 onwards) and see which is nearest to your place.

Answer (score 0):

Mantras are well thought and powerful words compiled by out intellectual ancestors. These words have the power to pull in the positive vibrations from the universe and hence bring us closer to peace and happiness. Mantras are great only if spelled properly. So, practice till you are a perfectionist!

Chant Life are magical mantras for a better life! Every Hindu should chant them regularly.

Comment: Welcome To Hinduism SE! Question-Answer forum about Hinduism.Pls. provide some sources in your answer to support it.Like quotes of acharyas , saints etc.Or citing from authentic Hindu Scriptures.